# Почему моя программа не рисует круг в pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qpainter

Я хочу нарисовать круг по нажатию на кнопку, но почему-то не получается. 
`.ui` файл должен быть обязательно. Помогите пожалуйста

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
import random
from PyQt5 import uic


class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
        self.draw = False
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.circle)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.run(qp)

    def run(self, qp):
        if self.draw:
            x = random.randint(10, 300)
            y = random.randint(10, 300)
            w = random.randint(10, 50)
            h = random.randint(10, 20)
            qp.drawEllipse(x, y, w, h)
            self.draw = False
            qp.end()

    def circle(self):
        self.draw = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**untitled.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>597</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Создать</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>597</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: У Вас логика рисования круга описана в `run` методе, но нет нигде вызова этого метода. Может, проблема в этом?

Comment: просто убери `self.draw = False` из run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import uic
from random import randint 


class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)

        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.circle)

        self.label = QLabel()  
        canvas = QPixmap(600, 600)
        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0)        

    def circle(self):
        x, y = [randint(10, 500) for i in range(2)]
        w, h = [randint(10, 100) for i in range(2)]        
        # создаем экземпляр QPainter, передавая холст (self.label.pixmap())
        painter = QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(3)
        pen.setColor(QColor(*[randint(0, 255) for i in range(3)]))  
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawEllipse(x, y, w, h)
        painter.end()
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно перевести QT интерфейс в *python*, а не в xml. Для этого откройте командную строку (cmd) и с помощью команды `cd` перейдите в папку с файлом. Далее введите следующую команду:

```
pyuic5 ui_file.ui -o ui_file.py
```

(**ui_file.ui** - имя вашего интерфейса, а **ui_file.py** - название, которое получит файл после преобразования), чтобы преобразовать интерфейс в python

Comment: Проблема явно не в этом. Я попробовал и с python файлом и с ui. Разницы нет.